# Cant get my python dictionary to work properly

Tags: python, dictionary

```
nums = [3,2,2,3]

hash = {}
        
for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i] not in hash:
        hash[nums[i]] = [i]
    else:
        hash[nums[i]] = hash[nums[i]].append(i)
        
print(hash)
```

What im trying to do here is add the indexes of occurrences of a certain element in a list as a list as a value to the key, which is the element itself.

For Example:-
`nums = [3,2,2,3]`
should return `{3: [0,3], 2: [1,2]`
instead, what my code returns is this:-
`{2: None, 3: None}`

Please tell me where I'm going wrong in my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hash[nums[i]] = hash[nums[i]].append(i)
```

append always returns none as it modifies the original list you instead need to do just

```
hash[nums[i]].append(i)
```

there everything else is fine.
Also you can use the built in enumerate function instead of your for loop

```
nums = [3,2,2,3]

hash = {}
        
for i, item in enumerate(nums):
    if item not in hash:
        hash[item] = [i]
    else:
        hash[item].append(i)
        
print(hash)
```

Comment: thank you so much! that worked like i wanted it to!

Comment: @PTTX Then please mark it as the accepted answer and also upvote it if not yet, you must respect and acknowledge any answer

Answer (score 0):

as juanpa.arrivillaga already commented, you should not overwrite your hash dict when appending to its values.

```
nums = [3, 2, 2, 3]

hash = {}
for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i] not in hash:
        hash[nums[i]] = [i]
    else:
        hash[nums[i]].append(i)

print(hash)
# {3: [0, 3], 2: [1, 2]}
```

---

a slightly more compact approach using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) und [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) gives you the same results.

```
hash = {}
nums = [3, 2, 2, 3]
for i, num in enumerate(nums):
    hash.setdefault(num, []).append(i)

print(hash)
# {3: [0, 3], 2: [1, 2]}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! yes i was overwriting my dict which caused None to appear! will use enumerate() from now on!